# How to update a modified string with good performance

Tags: javascript, string, performance

I am creating a document which can be modified by many users at the same time. To simplify the document can be thought of as a string. At the moment when a modification is made the whole string is sent to all the clients and their version of the string is replaced with the new one. This is very heavy for big strings in terms of the amount of data being sent over the network. And so i want to just send as little as possible even if that means a bit more work client side.

I am using javascript but that is not important.

I have started by saving the string as a variable "oldstring" and after a modification I have the variable "newstring". I send the variable "message" (which at the moment is equal to "newstring"). "message" is recieved by all clients and using it their "oldstring" is updated

All help is greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to achieve this using the [Google Diff/Match/Patch library](https://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch). It has bindings for Python, C++, Java, LUA, Objective C, and Javascript. You would download the original to the client, generate a list of patches on the server-side (you'd want to keep track of which client had which version to know what your starting point is; this can be done on the client or the server), pull the patches for the client's local revision to the latest down to the client, and use the client-side library to apply the patches. Once you get the changes in, you'd want to update that client revision tracking number.

I've included an implementation sample for completeness' sake. I'm pretty impressed with how well this library works and intend to keep it in my toolbelt.

```
// C# server-side code
DiffMatchPatch.diff_match_patch differ = new DiffMatchPatch.diff_match_patch();
// I'm using literals, you'd pull these from a DB, etc.
var results = differ.patch_make("ABCDEFG", "ABCDEFQ");
var serializedResults = differ.patch_toText(results);
// Send serializedResults to client...
```

On the client-side:

```
// Javascript client-side code
var patcher = new diff_match_patch();
// The below literal is what *would* be sent
var patches = patcher.patch_fromText("@@ -3,5 +3,5 @@\n CDEF\n-G\n+Q\n");
var results = patcher.patch_apply(patches, 'ABCDEFG');
alert(results);
```